# Error using Chrome React Developer Tools with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

After creating a new create-react-app project  I've run into a bit of a big problem when I run npm start inside the project. Chrome React Developer tools does not show all files in src folder. Instead it shows only folder ./src
[Chrome React Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JoHF.jpg)

I am using nodejs 6.10.1 , create-react-app 1.3.0.

package.json:

```
     {
      "name": "test",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "prop-types": "^15.5.9",
        "react": "^15.5.4",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.10",
        "react-bootstrap-table": "^3.2.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
        "react-router": "^3.0.0",
        "recharts": "^0.22.3",
        "redux": "^3.6.0",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
        "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
    }
```

Any advice how to fix it? I checked documentation but didn't find any solution.

Comment: are you expecting the full files from project's root directory?

Comment: I am expecting all files under src folder. I think it is Webpack server issue.

Comment: Well that's because webpack has bundled all of your front end assets. If you want to look at specific part of your code, you will need to look at the sourcemaps.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can still debug the code using VScode Chrome extension, however its not my favorite way of debugging a frontend application.

Use  `eject` command to enable debugging. 
After you `npm run eject`, it reveals more configurations for you to edit, one of those is source-map type (under a webpack configuration). Once you eject, the source-map type changes thus allowing you to debug on chrome-dev-tools.